# Play Minecraft Classic Server when Minecraft.net is down?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I run my own Minecraft Classic server and I was wondering if it is possible to *play it without logging on to minecraft.net*. Minecraft is down all the time (including now) so I was wondering if there was a way for me to set up the server specially and download a client to play it.

Thanks

Comment: "Classic multiplayer is probably down due to errors in the application layer. Will have to take a look at it tomorrow." -- Tobias Mollstam's twitter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. If you change online-mode to false in server.properties, you can still play on that server while minecraft.net is down, since it doesn't try to check your username against the database. A word of advice, this will open you up to major griefing and it only allows one person to log in at a time.

Comment: Thanks for that, yeah I understood that could happen. For the time being I have the online-mode to false and am accessing it via a direct link at http://www.minecraft.net/play.net?ip=SERVERIP&port=25560&override=true. Thanks for the great answer.